# Get Document from Sharepoint 2007 document library to sharepoint 2010 document library

Tags: development, document-library

I have a requiremement in my project that i need to pull the document in Sharepoint 2007 document library and need to add it in Sharepoint 2010 document library. I have already developed that puuling the document to Shared location and adding it to Sharepoint 2010 document library by using "Client Object Model". But here i didn't get any idea on how to get and add document from 2007 to 2010.

Comment: This has to be done programmatically without user input? Or drag and drop? Can you use server-side code or it has to be through web services?

Answer (score 1):

Done with using Webservice. Created a intermediate folder in the file system and updating it to sharepoint 2010 site immediatly. No body can remove that folder in the runtime because it is use:). After that there is no problem by removing the folder:). Done this by using Win-forms.

Regards,
Suresh Pydi

Answer (score 0):

For downloading

[Download Documents FROM Moss 2007 using C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmyancs/archive/2007/09/15/how-to-download-files-from-a-sharepoint-document-library-remotely-via-lists-asmx-webservice-sps-2003-moss-2007.aspx)

For Uploading

[Uploading Documents to SHarepoint 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876598/sharepoint-2010-uploading-documents)

[Another Post](http://www.sadev.co.za/content/upload-files-sharepoint-using-odata)

I mean it just take few searches on Google and yu can find these scripts easily then why asking other to search them for you :)

Cheers

Comment: Hi, I don't want any intermediate process over here. Just need to Move from Source to destination. I mean Sharepoint 2007 to sharepoint 2010. I already got this links from google. But i didn't get any thing related to Directly moving to Sharepoint 2007 to sharepoint 2010 document library.

Comment: why do you mean by directly ?

Comment: How come i'll accept dude....I didn't get any proper answer for questions  ;-)

Comment: If you dont get proper answers then how did you solved your previous questions and moved forwarded, you should answer your own question as well if you find a answer or solved your problem somehow, you can't keep asking question over questions and dont accept any answer or give answers yourself :)